# Query join result appears to be incorrect

Tags: postgresql, left-join

I have no idea what's going on here. Maybe I've been staring at this code for too long.

The query I have is as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW v_sku_best_before AS
  SELECT
    sw.sku_id,
    sw.sku_warehouse_id  "A",
    sbb.sku_warehouse_id "B",
    sbb.best_before,
    sbb.quantity
  FROM SKU_WAREHOUSE sw
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SKU_BEST_BEFORE sbb
      ON sbb.sku_warehouse_id = sw.warehouse_id
  ORDER BY sbb.best_before
```

I can post the table definitions if that helps, but I'm not sure it will. Suffice to say that `SKU_WAREHOUSE.sku_warehouse_id` is an identity column, and `SKU_BEST_BEFORE.sku_warehouse_id` is a child that uses that identity as a foreign key.

Here's the result when I run the query:

```
+--------+-----+----+-------------+----------+
| sku_id |  A  | B  | best_before | quantity |
+--------+-----+----+-------------+----------+
|  20251 | 643 | 11 | <<null>>    |      140 |
+--------+-----+----+-------------+----------+
(1 row)
```

The join specifies that the `sku_warehouse_id` columns have to be equal, but when I pull the ID from each table (labelled as `A` and `B`) they're different.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps just `sw.sku_warehouse_id` instead of `sw.warehouse_id`?

Comment: Thanks, Nerdwood. I clearly have been staring at this for too long... doh!

Comment: No problem, I definitely know the feeling!